# Convert some dataframe rows into columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I looked for other answers, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I have this dataframe:

```
Category 3,Chapter I,Category 2,Category 1,Chapter II,Chapter III
prima,126,Immediate corrections,Immediate corrections,97,83
da,38,Small late single corrections,Late corrections,24,24
sps.,22,Late single corrections written above,Late corrections,17,18
```

I want this to be:

```
    prima, da, sps.,
  Chapter I  126, 38, 22
  Chapter II 97, 24, 17
  Chapter III 83, 24, 18
```

Category I groups the other categories and I don't know what to do with them, they can also be deleted.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered doing the transpose of the dataframe after setting your column category 3 as index?

Imagine df is:

```
    a   b
0   1   7
1   2   8
2   3   9
```

Then:

```
df.set_index("a")
df.T

a   1   2   3
b   7   8   9
```

And you can finally filter those columns you are interested in using `loc`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.drop([x for x in df.columns if not 'Chapter' in x], axis=1).T
```

Comment: Please provide more info. Code only answer are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing both answers below:

```py
df.set_index('Category 3')[[x for x in df.columns if 'Chapter' in x]].T
```